# Posso considerar que minha aplicação está em MVC?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Pesoal, seguinte: estou meio que com uma dúvida conceitual.

Comecei a implementar minha aplicação (c# - forms) pensando em seguir o desenvolvimento baseado na arquitetura MVC. Mas, intuitivamente - e não sei se conceitualmente correto - acabei efetuando a seguinte divisão (coloquei a imagem do diagrama de classes para facilitar):

Classe 'formularioPrincipal': responsável por apresentar os dados e notificar eventos e ações do usuário na interface do sistem para a classe 'arvoreCont'.

Classe 'arvoreCont': recebe as requisições do formulário, solicita dados ao banco pela classe *persistence*, aplica regras de negócio e retorna para a *view*.

Classe *persistence*: faz toda a comunicação com o banco para inclusão, alteração, exclusão e consulta de dados (com filtros `where`).

Classes 'no', 'dados' e 'transacao' que representam os objetos da aplicação que são utilizados muitas vezes para passar dados para a interface.

[image: Diagrama de classes]

Não sei se conceitualmente posso considerar que utilizei o MVC, até porque, pelo que li, a classe *persistence* deveria estar junto com as classes que representam os objetos. Mas, para mim, faz sentido separar.

E o que inicialmente tratei como *controller* (classe 'arvoreCont') acabou responsável pela centralização de grande parte da regra de negócio.

Posso dizer, baseado nessa estrutura, que uso MVC? A intenção inicial era utilizar, mas no fim, não sei se consegui. O que acham?

Comment: Você só tem uma view? Ou suas views estendem `formularioPrincipal`?

Comment: Eu tenho várias views, que representam os formulários exibidos ao usuário.
Eu estou exibindo apenas um "pedaço" para não ficar muita coisa. Mas o funcionamento para as outras views é semelhante. Ela interage com um controler, que por sua vez interage com o persistence.
Elas não estendem o formulário principal.

Comment: Eu não diria que é MVC se o controller tem regra de negócio - ele deveria ter no máximo as regras de aplicativo.

Comment: O que você considera como 'regras de aplicativo'?

Comment: Exemplo de regra de aplicativo: o usuário solicita uma lista de clientes, o aplicativo sabe qual model e view selecionar enviar para o usuário - isso é uma regra de aplicativo. Então regras de aplicativo são o fluxo de navegação no sistema, as permissões de acesso, a gestão de logs, o conhecimento de quais regras de negócio acionar para atender requisições do usuário... (obs: ao dirigir-se a alguém, faça-o através do seu nome com um @ na frente, assim o usuário é notificado da sua mensagem).

Comment: @Caffé, obrigado pelas respostas. Entendi  o que colocou...
Então, como tinha imaginado eu acabei não utilizando um "padrão" de arquitetura... :(

O correto seria mover todas as regras de negócio para as entidades do model, a saber, classe: "Nó", "Função de dados" e "Funçao transacao". Certo?

Seria 'correto' dentro do MVC criar uma outra classe persisnte que centralize o acesso ao banco, ou também deveria em uma única classe com as regras de negócio - no model.? Obrigado

Comment: MVC é um design pattern de apresentação, ele não determina a responsabilidade da persistência (ele só sabe que não é uma responsabilidade dele). De qualquer modo, quanto melhor separadas estiverem as responsabilidades, em todas as camadas, melhor - ou seja: separe à vontade a persistência das regras de negócio.

Comment: @Caffé, está claro. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vamos definir conceituamente o que é MVC, e então traçar um paralelo com sua solução.

Da nossa *tag* [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc):

> Model-view-controller (MVC), em português modelo-visão-controlador, é um modelo de arquitetura de software que separa a representação da informação da interação do usuário com ele.

Neste modelo, temos três camadas muito bem definidas:

> Um **Modelo** (*model*) consiste nos dados da aplicação, regras de negócios, lógica e funções, bem como a descrição do relacionamento entre outros modelos.
>
> Uma **Visão** (*view*) pode ser qualquer saída de representação dos dados, como uma tabela ou um diagrama. É possível ter várias visões do mesmo dado, como um gráfico de barras para gerenciamento e uma visão tabular para contadores.
>
> Um **Controlador** (*controller*) faz a mediação das entradas e estabelece como deve ser a interação entre modelos e alimentando as informações das visões.

O que você apresentou como solução basicamente tem:

1. Um intermediador entre apresentação e modelos, `arvoreCont`, que possui funções que lidam com apresentação e modelos, mas altamente acoplada a ambos;
2. Uma camada de apresentação ancestral, `formularioPrincipal`, que, aparentemente, é a base de toda e qualquer tela que você desenvolver;
3. Uma camada de modelos, aparentemente gerenciada pelo intermediador.

Eu não diria que esta arquitetura é MVC. Diria que isto é uma **arquitetura simples de 3 camadas** com grau elevado de acoplamento e baixa coesão, onde temos:

- Uma camada de apresentação;
- Uma camada de negócio;
- Uma camada de persistência e acesso a dados.

No MVC, a estratificação faz com que a camada controladora tenha apenas o suficiente para harmonizar o fluxo de informação entre apresentação e modelos. Não parece ser seu caso.

A camada de modelo contém a maior parte das regras conceituais de negócio da aplicação, e por *design*. É nela que ficam as especificações de cada tipo de informação, as validações feitas sobre o conjunto de informações, as restrições, e assim por diante. Também não parece ser o caso. A camada que você implementou parece ser apenas o agente de acesso a uma base de dados, dependente da camada intermediária.

A camada que mais se assemelha a MVC, no seu caso, é a apresentação, ainda que tenha métodos de notificação de informações à camada intermediária, o que também a torna dependente de ações desta camada intermediária, o que não ocorre no MVC.